# Contextualize technology in a question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, posting

Sometimes, reviewing questions I wonder if the fact of explaining the problem directly without contextualize the issue (I mean, without giving details about the technologies and frameworks involved) is a reason to request more information, if it is correctly tagged with that information.

I am in favor of starting the question with an introductory paragraph, but on the other hand, if that information is provided by the tags and there is no relevant data omitted, it is a way of going straight to the matter.

Are there any guidelines defined in that sense?

Comment: Tags already provide context. Whether they provide *enough* context for the reader or whether a question would do better with some additional introductory text very much depends on the question and writing style. A question should get to the point ASAP, so spending too many words upfront for context which tags already provide will just annoy readers.

Comment: To extend on deceze's comment: keep in mind that a Q&A are there for future readers as well. So when someone finds a question via search engine, then they want to verify the question applies to their case and they can do that much better, when the question only contains required information and no other context. That just "hides the needle in a haystack".

Comment: Completely agree, that is the point of my question. Reviewing has given me the perspective that sometimes too much contextualization could be counterproductive. Thank you!

Comment: A context has to be *useful*. Saying "I use X library" and then tagging with `x` conveys the same information. However, "I use X library for result Y" can be more substantial - perhaps you don't want people to suggest result Z or it might turn out that X is not needed to do Y.

Comment: I always provide motivating context in my questions. It tends to make the questions longer, sometimes significantly so. Opinions differ on whether or not that is a good thing. I don't see a problem with it; if you don't want to read it all, you can skim/skip it. But I'm sure the length does put off some folks from reading my questions entirely, I'm OK with that. What about you?

Comment: FWIW I sometimes don't see the tags when I start reading a question, so I don't think it amiss if that information is included *somewhere* in the question. What is a problem is a long description of background information that is not directly relevant to the problem. I ran into a Q like that today and took the time to re-order the info as it was a good question, otherwise - put the background info at the end where those who are interested at the level can still read it, if they want.